# How to display first 6 and last author in reference list, using apa style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

This questions regards the Bibliography/Reference List at the end of the document NOT the in-text citation.

I want to use apa-good.bst as my bibliography style. Some of my references have way more than 7 authors. Following the guidelines for APA style citations, the first 6 authors should be listed followed by "..." and then the last author. After intense googling I did not find a sufficient solution. My plan would be to modify the **FUNCTION {format.names}** but my coding knowledge in LaTeX is quite bad. I only managed to enter the part, where it reduces the total author list to 7 authors. 
It now reads:

```
FUNCTION {format.names} 
{ 'bibinfo :=  
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {  
's := 
 "" 't :=
 #1 'nameptr :=
 s num.names$ 'numnames :=
 numnames 'namesleft :=
{ namesleft #0 > }
{ s nameptr
  "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
  format.name$
  bibinfo bibinfo.check
  't :=
  nameptr #1 >
     {
    nameptr #7
    #1 + =
    numnames #7 
   > and
    { "others" 't :=
    #1 'namesleft := }
    'skip$
    if$
       namesleft #1 >
        { ", " * t * }
        {
          "," *
          s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
            { 't := }
            { pop$ }
          if$
          t "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            {
              "\&"
              space.word * t *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    't
  if$
  nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
  namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}  while$
  } if$
}
```

This reduces the authors list to max 7 authors but instead the "Author 6, ..., Author 70" it gives "Author 6, et. al".

Do you have an idea how, respectively where to change the Function to match the guidelines? [APA-style 6thedition, 7or more authors[1](http://guides.himmelfarb.gwu.edu/c.php?g=27779&p=170336)

Thank you for your time and ideas,

Lucy

Comment: Doesn't actually answer your question, but could you move to `biblatex`? `biblatex-apa` supports this out of the box.

Comment: Also where can we find `apa-good.bst`? It does not appear to be in CTAN.

Comment: Dear David, thank you for your pompt response.  I will look into biblatex, does it also support \citep{} and is the ciation in text also following the apa-style guidelines? (all authors for one or two,First Author et. al. for 3 and more authors) in the in-text-citations?                                                                                                                regarding the apa-good.bst file, I got it from here https://github.com/unaguil/thesis-latex/blob/master/Latex/StyleBST/apa-good.bst

Comment: As far as I know `biblatex-apa` has been written to adhere to the requirements of APA very closely. `biblatex` is much more flexible than `natbib` and the output of `biblatex-apa` should be superior to any `bst` file. `biblatex` uses `\parencite` and `\textcite` in place of `\citep` and `\citet`, but the latter can be used with a `natbib` compatibility option to `biblatex`. Note that you **can not** load the `natbib` package with `biblatex`. They are incompatible.

Comment: Thank you for all this input David, I tried a little but have the feeling I have to read myself a little into the whole biblatex mechanic to proper use it. since I have a lot of chapters and hundreds of citations I would have to replace the shortcuts in all chapters, so I will have to see if I have the time to explore the biblatex option. But still, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't perform the equivalent of reinventing the wheel by hacking the `apa-good` bibliography style. Instead, I'd use `apacite` LaTeX package and the `apacite` bibliography style. They jointly implement exactly what you're looking for in terms of typesetting bibliographic entries with eight or more authors/editors.

If you want to be able to use the natbib-style citation commands, such as `citet` and `\citep`, simply load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc...xyz:3001,
  author = "A and B and C and D and E and F and G and X and Y and Z",
  title = "Thoughts",
  year  = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, thank you very much for this hint. I changed to \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} and YES it solves the issue for my Reference list/Bibliography at the end of document. BUT unfortunately I now have the issue with the in text citations, where no "et al." is displayed for more than two authors. If you are experienced with apacite, do you maybe know a solution for that out of your head? Cheers, Lucy

Comment: @Lucy -- The current APA formatting guidelines for citation call-outs to bib entries with between 3 and 5 authors state that (a) the first time a piece is cited, the citation call-out should list all authors and (b) from the second citation call-out onward, the "first-surname et al" truncation convention should be used. Separately, If an entry has more than 5 authors, even the very first citation call-out will use the truncation convention.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still of utility, I modified the original `format.names` in `apa-good.bst` to insert the new standard. It should be something like this

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
      { namesleft #1 >
        nameptr #7 <
        and
          { ", " * t * }
          { numnames #2 >
            nameptr #7 <
            and
              { "," * }
              'skip$
              if$
            t "others" =
              { " ..." * }
              { nameptr #7 <
                nameptr numnames =
                or
                numnames #7 >
                and
                  {", ..., and " * t * }
                  { nameptr #7 <
                    nameptr numnames =
                    or
                      {" and " * t * }
                      'skip$
                    if$
                  }
                if$
              }
            if$
          }
        if$
      }
      numnames #7 >
      nameptr #7 >
      nameptr numnames <
      and and
        {"" 't :=}
        'skip$
        if$
      't
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```